# counting different types of zeroes in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, count, dataframe

I have a slightly complicated "data_frame" in the sense that the columns have zeroes stored with different decimal points.
So for example one column has zeroes as 0, the other as 0.0, the other as 0.000 and so on.
I am trying to count all the zeroes in each column of the data frame so when I code:

```
>colSums(data_frame==0)
```

I only get the number of zeros in columns that have zero values stored as 0. The others with zeros as 0.00, 0.000.... etc show up as NA count.
This is the format of the data

```
str(data_frame)
 $ P0           : num  0 0 1 1 2 0 0 2 2 5 ...
 $ P1           : num  8 10 2 0 5 0 6 4 2 5 ...
 $ P2           : num  8 7 4 0 5 1 6 10 2 8 ...
 $ P3           : num  7 6 2 3 6 6 6 2 2 10 ...
 $ P4           : num  3 14.62 2 1.12 3 ...
 $ P.x          : num  6.5 9.4062 1.5 0.0312 2.75 ...
 $ InvN.x        : num  0.8792 1.505 -0.5619 -1.1856 -0.0886 ...
 $ h1           : num  65 80 75 40 86 32 75 40 60 76 ...
 $ h2           : num  65 75 65 60 86 74 45 0 60 60 ...
 $ h3           : num  80 75 75 70 61 91 44 33 40 75 ...
 $ h4           : num  65 60 60 45 50 84 40 75 80 85 ...
 $ meanh        : num  68.8 72.5 68.8 53.8 70.8 ...
 $ PQ1          : num  1.663 2.812 0.23 0.015 0.762 ...
 $ PQ2          : num  1.755 2.525 0.578 0.125 1.133 ...
 $ PQ3          : num  1.843 2.217 0.54 -0.02 0.307 ...
 $ change       : int  21 24 7 3 12 12 18 12 5 15 ...
 $ meanbin      : int  15 18 15 5 16 16 3 1 8 19 ...
```

Can someone please help?
Thanks.

Comment: Are your columns all of class `numeric`? If not, use `as.numeric` and try again.

Comment: How is your `data_frame` structured? Are the values stored as text strings? I.e. `"0.0"` or are they numeric/integer? Can you `dput(head(data_frame))` so that we don't need to guess?

Comment: I edited the question. Please see above for the format of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have numerics, your comparisons are subject to floating point errors. Instead of `==`, you want to do something like:

```
colSums(abs(data_frame) < epsilon)
```

for some small `epsilon` of your choice: something that makes sense given your data precision. An extreme value might be what the `all.equal` function uses as default tolerance: `.Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5`.

Comment: so did it work for you? please consider voting and accepting the answer.

Comment: sorry, I've had to work on a didferent data set. i will say if it worked or not tomorrow

Answer (score -1):

You can `grep` the `.` (dot) in that column to get a vector of indices where that cell has `0.0` or `0.00` and so on. Then you can manually assign those cells as `NA`. Finally you continue to use `colSums(data_frame==0)` and remember to specify `na.rm=TRUE`.

Comment: You should wait to hear if the data.frame contains characters or numerics. Regardless, your solution will not work if the data contains numbers like `1.5`...

Comment: Counterexample: `grep("\\.", data.frame(a=factor(seq(0,1,length=10)))  )`